# How to disable child row in Responsive Datatable jQuery after paging

Tags: jquery, datatable

Step to procedure:

- I try to render content in reponsive table like in this tutorial:
  https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/custom-renderer.html
- Click on expand button in any row on page 1, the extra information for table show up
- Click on paging button 2, then click back button 1, extra information is always visible(actually I want extra information is invisible here).

  [image]
- Are there any solution to hide extra information in responsive jDatatable after click on paging button?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: oh I think that's a bit tricky, but possible :)
first have a look, what happens, if you click on an expand button. --> a new `<tr></tr>` comes up with class="child" and the <tr> where you clicked gets the class "parent". I think, you can add a click event on paginate_button and remove all tr.child and remove the class parent on tr.parent. I thnik it will be helpful, if you post a code snipped on JSFiddle, where we can try a bit and look which functions are given by DataTable. best regards Eldo.Ob

Comment: Thanks a lot, The solution below works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: {
            details: {
                renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                    var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                        return col.hidden ?
                            '<tr data-dt-row="'+col.rowIndex+'" data-dt-column="'+col.columnIndex+'">'+
                                '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                                '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>' :
                            '';
                    } ).join('');

                    return data ?
                        $('<table/>').append( data ) :
                        false;
                }
            }
        }
    } );

   $('#example').on( 'page.dt', function () {
       $(".parent .sorting_1").click();
    } );
} );
```

Based on the example I have created [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/52/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks very much Aneesh, it works like a champ. it is really a perfect solution